# php - need help converting a python command to php code sha256

Tags: python, php, sha256

I'm using the python hashlib to get a condensed sha256 value using the following command, can someone help me out with a compatible function?

```
import hashlib

biz_number = "000-00-00000"
total_amount = "45000"
external_auth_key = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
signature = hashlib.sha256(':'.join([biz_number, external_auth_key, total_amount]).encode()).hexdigest()
print(signature)

> b9c4510deb7e279687bac8503d12f0878e0955a0f247b9257cb600df10378895
```

Comment: I tried to do this.
`base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', join(':', [$biz_number, $external_auth_key, $total_amount]), ''));`

Comment: I found the answer.
`hash('sha256', join(':', [$biz_number, $external_auth_key, $total_amount]))`